# Entity framework 6, very slow creating new entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a method that reads a text file, parse it and create (or update) entities from my DB.
The code is simple:
1- Read/Parse the file and create a list
2- loop in this list, first see if the product is found, if not it creates it.
3- update the properties 
4- Save the context outside the loop

The problem is that on every iteration of the loop the creation part (the section inside the if) takes longer and longer.

My question is:
Is this the best approach to add entities to a context?
Can this be improved somehow?

I'm pretty new to the Entity Framework and not sure if I'm using it correctly. 
BTW, the context was created in the calling method.

Thank for you suggestions.

CODE:

```
  public void ImportProduct(MyContext context, string sourceFile)
  {
  List<Product> newProducts = ParseItems(sourceFile);
  var currentProductsMap = context.Products.ToDictionary(x => x.OriginalId, x => x);
  foreach (var item in newProducts)
  {
    var id = item.OriginalId;
    Product product;
    if (!currentProductsMap.TryGetValue(id, out product))
    {
        product = context.Products.Create();
        product.OriginalId = id;
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    product.UPC = string.Empty;
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, Entity Framework isn't a very good choice for importing large amounts of data from another source.  The Context will cache every object you insert, making queries take longer and longer as the import process goes on.  It's more geared to specific actions taken against a business object with short a short lived Context.  You can avoid some of the slowdown if you batch inserts and dispose of the Context and recreate it between batches, but that always feels "hacky" to me.

Comment: I'm adding around 5000-6000 entities. Not sure if this is considered "large"

Comment: I tried to do something similar when I first started using EF and ran in to the same problem.  I had performance issues if I didn't recreate the context after about 500 inserts.  EF Contexts really are designed and optimized to be short lived.  They have serious performance issues if you keep them alive too long.

Comment: Have you considered importing the data inside SQL Server Management Studio? There is an import tool for CSV etc. There other possibility is to use SSIS if you are trying to automate the process...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the obvious reason for the slowdown is that Entity Framework only ever submits data once your foreach is done, meaning you could easily collect more data than your application can buffer. A simple workaround would be to call the submit/save in regular intervals of the loop and see if this changes anything. Keep track of your memory usage!

Before you start to go deep into EF-optimizations, might I suggest having a look at [Entity Framework Bulk Insert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/), which is designed for inserting large amounts of data quickly.

Comment: I do not believe this is the case in hand, I have only 5432 items to process.
I cannot use the bulk insert cause I do insert/update in the same loop

Answer (score 0):

The following line may be causing your issue:

```
product = context.Products.Create();
```

This [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679407(v=vs.113).aspx) says "Creates a new instance of an entity for the type of this set. Note that this instance is NOT added or attached to the set. The instance returned will be a proxy if the underlying context is configured to create proxies and the entity type meets the requirements for creating a proxy."

So, it's seems possible that it extra work is being done for dynamic proxy creation that you may not be expecting.

Perhaps you should try again with something like:

```
var product = new Product();
```

Comment: @ignacio - I saw your answer below. Were you able to evaluate each of the three bullet points in isolation to see which provided the biggest boost in performance? I believe using new Product() probably had the largest impact.

Comment: I believe it was the AutoDetectChangesEnabled setting the one that had the biggest impact, but not 100% sure of it. 
The creation of the context not, as the context was "almost new"
If I have time today I will do do that test and post back the results
Thank for posting

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void ImportProduct(string file)
    {
        using (var context = new LaceupDatabase()) {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            if (context == null)
                return;
            List<Product> products = ParseItems(file);
            var productMap = context.Products.ToDictionary(x => x.OriginalId, x => x);
            foreach (var item in products) {
                var id = item.OriginalId;
                Product product;
                bool modified = false;
                bool newItem = false;
                if (!productMap.TryGetValue(id, out product)) {
                    product = new Product();
                    product.OriginalId = id;
                    modified = true;
                    newItem = true;
                }
                else
                    // This is a reference to another entity
                    if (product.Category != null && item.Category != null && product.Category.Id != item.Category.Id) {
                        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
                        product.Category = item.Category;
                        // product.CategoryId = item.Category.Id;
                        modified = false;
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                    }
                if (newItem || product.Code != item.Code) {
                    product.Code = item.Code;
                    modified = true;
                }
                if (newItem) {
                    context.Products.Add(product);
                    context.Entry(product).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                    if (modified)
                        context.Entry(product).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
  }
```

Hi again,

This is the code I'm currently testing, I'm still using the AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false as it is the biggest performance gainer. 
The problem this entail is that I have to keep track if the entity was changed to mark it as Modified.

The biggest problem though is the case of one property of an entity type, for some reason that property was not being updated even after marking the instance as Modified, so I ended needing to set the AutoDetectChangesEnabled to true, make the change and persist it to the DB.

Again, the code is far from pretty, but it seems to perform efficiently and so far has no fail.

If anybody has another suggestion I would really appreciate it.

Thank,
Ignacio